# How to get HMONITOR information in MSDN Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

What I require to do is pass a handle to the primary monitor to the [DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows so that the RECT of DesktopCoordinates has only the primary monitor dimensions even if multiple monitors are connected.

Here is the structure of DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC:

```
typedef struct DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC {
  WCHAR              DeviceName[32];
  RECT               DesktopCoordinates;
  BOOL               AttachedToDesktop;
  DXGI_MODE_ROTATION Rotation;
  HMONITOR           Monitor;
} DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC;
```

However I referred to almost all [GetMonitorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions in the MSDN directory which have HMONITOR parameter but all are *In* and none of them return a Handle to the monitor.

So basically my question is what function or command do I use so that a handle to the primary monitor is returned which then I can modify in the DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC in order to modify the RECT of DesktopCoordinates to match the dimensions of the primary monitor.

This question is obviously for the case when there are multiple monitors connected to the system but I require the dimensions only of the primary monitor.

Answer (score 5):

Raymond Chen gives the answer [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/09/4300545.aspx).

Here's the most important part:

> The primary monitor by definition has its upper left corner at (0, 0). Therefore, you can use this function:
>
> ```
> HMONITOR GetPrimaryMonitorHandle()
> {
>     const POINT ptZero = { 0, 0 };
>     return MonitorFromPoint(ptZero, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
> }
> ```